# Openapi date format validation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a POST rest service that receive dates, one in queryParameter and the other one in requestBody. Here are parts of the yaml definition.

```
paths:
...
parameters:
        - in: query
          name: queryDate
          schema:
            type: string
            format: date
```

```
schemas:
...
TestObject:
      type: object
      properties:
        bodyDate:
          type: string
          format: date
```

The format is *date*, not *date-time*, so I expect to get a date like

- "2021-08-23"
  and not like
- "2021-08-23T05:39:12Z"

**QueryDate is OK**
This behaviour works well for *queryDate*, the *query parameter*.

- If I put *"2021-08-23"*, I get a HTTP 200, which is **correct**.
- If I put *"2021-08-23T05:39:12Z"* I get a 400 error Bad request, which is **correct**.

**bodyDate is NOK**
This behaviour is different for *bodyDate*, contained in the *requestBody*.

- If I put *"2021-08-23"*, I get a HTTP 200 which is **correct**.
- If I put *"2021-08-23T05:39:12Z"*, I get a HTTP 200, which is **NOT CORRECT** -> I should get a HTTP 400 error for bad request.

I tried to add a *pattern* to *bodyDate* but it adds an *@Pattern* annotation on the generated TestObject.queryDate field which is already a LocalDate so it does not work.

Is there a way to force the validation of bodyDate to respect the format yyyy-mm-dd without removing *"format: date"*?
Thanks

Comment: What software are you using to process these requests and validate based on the OpenAPI spec? Each implementation of OpenAPI will be slightly different, and may contain bugs. I suspect you have just found one of them

Comment: Thanks for your question. I use openapi-generator-maven-plugin (5.1.0) to generate model and api in my springboot Java application.

Comment: And I test application using swagger

Comment: I meant how are you doing the validation. Are you using Hibernate Validator or something similar?

Comment: actually I don't perform any manual validation, but if I tried to put a pattern, the message complains with a No Hibernate validator for Pattern on localDate. So I guess the response to your question is Hibernate validator.

Comment: Other information: if I add 
`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` above `public LocalDate getCreatedDate() {` in the generated model class. It works. 
But it makes no sense to edit manually a generated class so I'd like to find a way to generate it from the openapi yaml specification.

Comment: this post have the same problem but is not solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55425645/can-we-generate-jsonformat-on-model-variable-using-swagger-generater